# Wordpress dynamic page handle in theme

Tags: url-rewriting

I am creating a wordpress theme

My index.php is working great

I would like only 3 urls on my website

1. `/` which is going to wp-content/themes/my-theme/index.php or an ther fine I do not have problem with file name
2. `/url1` which is going to wp-content/themes/my-theme/dynamic.php
3. `/url2` which is going to wp-content/themes/my-theme/dynamic.php

I already made some intents updating the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/my-theme/dynamic.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But the wordpress logic is only loaded on `/` on the other urls I can not call wordpress functions.

I also made some tests with `add_rewrite_rule` but apache is returning me a 404 if I am not going to `/`

To sum up I would like all my urls managed by a single file then I will be doing the dispatch with php logic, this logic should also handle the root path (`/`)

The only url I do not want to rewrite is /wp-admin

Comment: You should never load theme PHP files directly, theme files do not control what WordPress does, it's the opposite way around. All traffic should be routed to `index.php`, and you should be using WP based rewrite rules and permalinks, not HTAcccess to do this

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, how should I  do to reach `dynamic.php` from `/url1` ? at the moment apache is returning a 404

Comment: Ok I had an issue with my wordpress in docker, the .htaccess has not been well generated and I did not have the redirect to the index.php. Restarting it it's working great

Comment: you don't, you make `url1` load a page and you assign the template to the page. Remember, the data determines the template, not the other way around. WP doesn't load your URL1 page because it hit `page.php`, WP loaded `page.php` because it hit URL1, your mental model of how it works is upside down and back to front. Aterall if it worked the way you think it works, you'd get a PHP fatal error the first time a WordPress function got used. URL creates query, query fetches posts, query determines theme template to load, WP loads chosen template ( based on the template hierarchy diagram )

Comment: Take a look at the template hierarchy diagram, things will make a lot more sense